# JMeter - Stop Thread Group and Start Next Thread Group

Tags: jmeter, threadgroup

I have 2 ThreadGroups in my TestPlan (I've checked the "Run Thread Groups Consecutively" option)

The first Thread Group is designed as follows:
a) Set the option for "Action to be taken after a Sampler error" as "Stop Thread"
b) Has a series of "HTTP Request" samplers as children.
c) One of the child Sampler has a Response Assertion that fails.

The second Thread Group is designed as follows:
a) Has one "HTTP Request" sampler.

The First Thread Group does stop due to one of the HTTP samplers having Response Assertion that fails. **However, the second Thread Group doesn't start in that case.**

When the Response Assertion is removed in the First Thread Group, the Second Thread Group executes successfully.

Why is that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've tested using JMeter 2.13 and it works for me without any issue.

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. What does your Java Request look like?

Comment: it just return ok except for the 2nd sampler where I put the response assertion to reproduce your case. Try showing your plan. Thanks

Comment: Well, my usecase is slightly different. I call one JMX from another JMX. The above setup is in the child JMX. The way I call the child JMX is by using an "OS Process Sampler" in the parent JMX, and calling a bat file that in turn calls the child JMX. I take the use of bat file due to the need of sending in parameters.

Comment: I've noticed that in the above mentioned setup the println statements I have in the child JMX using "BeanShell PreProcessor" don't show on the console. Must be because of the child is invoked internally. This makes debugging difficult.

Comment: ok, so what you describe in this question is not what you do in comment, I suggest you accept this answer and open another question describing fully with figure if possible what you are doing.